# Odoo - 403: Forbidden The page you were looking for could not be authorized

Tags: authentication, web, odoo, rights, qweb

I have made a web interface in Odoo which lists a tasks for the logged in user. The problem is that when a user does not have Administration Access Rights, the user is not able to see the page. Instead user sees the 403: Forbidden The page you were looking for could not be authorized error page. I do not want to assign Access Rights to every user. What is the solution to this problem?

Below method is called when the web page is loaded:

```
    @http.route(['/tasks'], auth='user', website=True)
    def list_tasks(self, **kw):

        task_pool = request.env['project.task']
        tasks = task_pool.search([('user_id', '=', request.uid)])

        if len(tasks) > 0:
            return request.render('pec.workstack', {
                'tasks': tasks
            })

        return request.redirect('/no_tasks')
```

Comment: Show us your code and the full text of the error message from logs.

Comment: There is no error message in the logs. I get re-routed to a page that says 403: Forbidden 
The page you were looking for could not be authorized.

Comment: The problem is most likely related to permissions on the `project.task` or other related models you read in your template. When I run Odoo from the console, in such cases there is always a message printed to the console, that includes information about the problematic model.

Answer (score 1):

While searching in the controller use sudo()

```
request.env['your.model'].sudo().search([(your domain)])
```